# Wordpress JS copy text script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to create a textarea where you can copy its contents to your clipboard. I found a script  on this board that explains the code but im having a hard time getting it to work on wordpress. The button doesnt perform the action correctly, nothing copies to the clipboard. The only thing I did different was the tag on the text. The original script uses `<input>` and i used `<textarea>`. I have this JS script running on the page only. Its not attached to the theme.

JS

```
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget"));
});

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
      // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
          succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

HTML

```
    <textarea type="text" id="copyTarget" class="">It's not that I'm so smart, it's just that I stay with problems longer.Albert Einstein</textarea>
<button id="copyButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Copy & Share</button>
```

Comment: just tried it on a wordpress theme - works fine.

Comment: Did you enqueue the script with [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)?  If not, how are you including it?

Comment: I didnt add it to wp_enqueue_script. I jused a plugin that allows me to add JS and CSS to the page.